# Members in A Guild

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this code that is supposed to send a list of members in a server that the bot is in, only with a guild id. Here is my code:

```
@client.command(name='members')
async def _members(ctx, guild_id: int):
  guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
  for m in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
    await ctx.send(f"{m}")
    await ctx.send("Done!")
```

But it doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why. I'm seriously stupid sometimes.
Here is the error I'm getting:

```
172.18.0.1 - - [05/Nov/2020 20:59:40] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Ignoring exception in command members:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 154, in _members
    for m in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
TypeError: 'MemberIterator' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'MemberIterator' object is not iterable
```

In addition, is there a way to remove all the bots from the list?

Answer (score 0):

`guild.fetch_members` returns an **asyncIterator** which means you should add the `async` keyoword before the for. But in your case if you will use the loop, it would cause spam, so we will just flatten the list and get the command working. Horray!
like that:

```py
@client.command(name='members')
async def _members(ctx, guild_id: int):
  guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
  x = await guild.fetch_members(limit=None).flatten()
  await ctx.send(x)
  await ctx.send("DONE")
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to separate it into multiple messages if the character limit is over 2000?

Answer (score 0):

According to the API References:

> Retrieves an AsyncIterator that enables receiving the guild’s members.

Also it says:

> **Note:** This method is an API call. For general usage, consider `members` instead.

But if you want to use `fetch_members` instead of `guild.members`, you can do 2 things to prevent this error.

- You can use `async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):`
  or
- `for member in await guild.fetch_members(limit=150).flatten():`.

But I suggest you to do what API References says and use `guild.members`.

Also, if you send messages in for loop, bot will spam so many messages, you should use `str.join()` method to send all members in one message. Here's what I mean:

```py
@client.command(name='members')
async def _members(ctx, guild_id: int):
  guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
  await ctx.send(', '.join(guild.members))
```

Or if you still want to send seperate messages, you can use this:

```py
@client.command(name='members')
async def _members(ctx, guild_id: int):
  guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
  for m in guild.members():
    await ctx.send(f'{m}')
    await ctx.send('DONE!')
```